# Pipeline not working in Apache Airflow with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, airflow

I am trying to form a simple pipeline where I first clean the dataframe then I store it in a CSV. The `clean_Data` task is failing and hence the task `store_data` is not working. I used the full path to write the dataframe as a CSV in the `store_data` task. I also first tried reading the csv in `clean_Data` locally, and I tried creating a dataframe without reading it from a CSV, but both are not working.

Here is the DAG script I wrote:

```
from airflow import DAG
import os
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
# import pandas and numpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 12, 5),
    'retries': 1
}


def storeData(**context):
    df= context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='clean_Data')
    df.to_csv('/c/Users/HP/airflowhome/dags/data/namesAge2.csv')


def cleanData():
    #df = df.read_csv('/c/Users/HP/airflowhome/dags/data/namesAge.csv')
    data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
            'Age': [np.nan, 21, np.nan, 18]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.fillna(0)
    return df


dag = DAG(
    'CleaningPipelineDAG',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Cleaning Data',
    schedule_interval='@once',
)


t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='clean_Data',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=cleanData,
    dag=dag,
)

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='store_data',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=storeData,
    dag=dag,
)

t1 >> t2
```

Here is the content of the log file:

```
[2020-12-09 13:50:55,984] {taskinstance.py:670} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: CleaningPipelineDAG.clean_Data 2020-12-09T11:45:26.969635+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-12-09 13:50:55,992] {taskinstance.py:670} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: CleaningPipelineDAG.clean_Data 2020-12-09T11:45:26.969635+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-12-09 13:50:55,992] {taskinstance.py:880} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-12-09 13:50:55,992] {taskinstance.py:881} INFO - Starting attempt 2 of 2
[2020-12-09 13:50:55,992] {taskinstance.py:882} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-12-09 13:50:56,004] {taskinstance.py:901} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): clean_Data> on 2020-12-09T11:45:26.969635+00:00
[2020-12-09 13:50:56,020] {standard_task_runner.py:54} INFO - Started process 1698 to run task
[2020-12-09 13:50:56,091] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'CleaningPipelineDAG', 'clean_Data', '2020-12-09T11:45:26.969635+00:00', '--job_id', '76', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER//c/Users/HP/DAG-3.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmpj92yjpoi']
[2020-12-09 13:50:56,094] {standard_task_runner.py:78} INFO - Job 76: Subtask clean_Data
[2020-12-09 13:50:56,169] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: CleaningPipelineDAG.clean_Data 2020-12-09T11:45:26.969635+00:00 [running]> on host mg.localdomain
[2020-12-09 13:50:56,189] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - cleanData() got an unexpected keyword argument 'conf'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 984, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/mg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/mg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
TypeError: cleanData() got an unexpected keyword argument 'conf'
[2020-12-09 13:50:56,191] {taskinstance.py:1187} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=CleaningPipelineDAG, task_id=clean_Data, execution_date=20201209T114526, start_date=20201209T115055, end_date=20201209T115056
[2020-12-09 13:51:00,984] {local_task_job.py:102} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Comment: what exactly is not working? exception? what is the issue?

Comment: @Elad I have updated my question with the log file. On the Airflow UI itself the clean_Data task's state is failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `**context` in `cleanData` callable.

This code executed OK:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 12, 5),
    'retries': 1
}


def storeData(**context):
    df= context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='clean_Data')
    print (df)


def cleanData(**context):
    data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
            'Age': [np.nan, 21, np.nan, 18]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.fillna(0)
    return df


dag = DAG(
    'CleaningPipelineDAG',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Cleaning Data',
    schedule_interval='@once',
)


t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='clean_Data',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=cleanData,
    dag=dag,
)

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='store_data',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=storeData,
    dag=dag,
)

t1 >> t2
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Why did you add **context in cleanData even though, I am not going to get an external arguments and insert them into the function?

Comment: @MarwaA. Then you need to remove the `provide_context=True` :)

Comment: What I read in a previous stackoveflow answer that both the function that is generating the parameter, and the function that is accepting it both should have `provide_context=True` isn't that correct?

Comment: Just look in the PythonOperator documntation:  `provide_context: if set to true, Airflow will pass a set of keyword arguments that can be used in your function. This set of kwargs correspond exactly to what you can use in your jinja templates. For this to work, you need to define **kwargs in your function header.`